# OpenCV setMouseCallback on Qt windows

Tags: python, qt, opencv

I am designing a PyQt interface for a video annotation tool. I would like to draw shapes over a video. I can load the video on a QLabel using OpenCV, but I cannot set the mouse callbacks to the PyQt window. Do I have to use an OpenCV namedWindow? As far as I know, OpenCV also uses a Qt backend.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app=QApplication(sys.argv)
  window=PythonOpenCVGUI()
  window.setWindowTitle('Python OpenCV GUI')
  cv2.setMouseCallback('Python OpenCV GUI', PythonOpenCVGUI.draw_circle)
  window.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Error:

```
cv2.setMouseCallback('Python OpenCV GUI', PythonOpenCVGUI.draw_circle)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp:714: error: (-27) NULL window handler in function cvSetMouseCallback
```

Comment: If you are using QtWidgets to display the images acquired by opencv you should not use setMouseCallback(), but the standard methodology that Qt offers to handle the mouse event since the owner of the window is Qt no opencv

Answer (score 0):

In https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_mouse_handling/py_mouse_handling.html they define a little function to draw the circle.

Use this example and modify it.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# mouse callback function
def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),100,(255,0,0),-1)

# Create a black image, a window and bind the function to window
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)#<=====here

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You must have mistaken. The OP seems to require an equivalent implementation when using PyQt